# How to match a word based on slash in regular expression

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a word with regex. for example, I want to match only first 2 folders in below string

```
/folder1/folder2/filder3/folder4/folder5
```

I wrote a below regex to match first two folders but it matches everything till /folder5 but I wanted to match only till /folder2

```
/(\w.+){2}
```

I guess .+ matches everything. Any idea how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^/[^/]+/[^/]+
^(?:/[^/]+){2}
```

Or, if you need to escape slashes:

```
^\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+
^(?:\/[^\/]+){2}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/56MarG/1). `[^/]` is a negated character class that matches any char other than a `/` char.

Comment: Thanks, can I use repeat something like {2}? I tried with (^/[^/]+){2} but it is not working

Comment: @MarioR You enclosed the `^` into the group, it must be outside, see my update.